# Django language field with translation

Tags: django, field

I want to create a language choice field but I am struggling to output the language field in the correct language.

Please find the source code below:

```
#settings.py
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-DE'

#model.py
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGES

class Language(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=LANGUAGES)


#formy.py 
class LanguageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Language
    fields = ['language']
```

And this is my view:

```
class LanguagesView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'adminarea/settings/subpages/tab_pane_settings_languages.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context                     = super(LanguagesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['lang_form']        = LanguageFormSet(instance=self.request.user.userstats)
```

And I render the form like that:

```
{{ lang_form }}
```

So if I render the form in my template I get the name of the language always in English. How can I use the correct translation depending on the language which is set in the django settings?

**Current workaround in my template:**

```
{% for x, y in mainlang_form.fields.language.choices %}
    <option value="{{ x }}">{% trans y %}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I avoid this workaround?

Comment: How are you setting the language to display the data in? Have you looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference?

Comment: I set the LANGUAGE_CODE in my settings.py. I don't use a middleware to change the language. The website has a fixed language.

Comment: Have you checked that the message translation files are correctly installed? And that they actually contain the strings that you want?

Comment: I've checked it. Everything seems to be okay. If I use {% trans "English" %} within my template, I see the correct translation.